# Asynctask tcpsocket Android

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I have a server running and when i send an httpget i get an image. This image i want to display into android so i'm using an asynctask to download the file. It works when I open an tcp scoket every time but when I want to open the socket when i push the button and close it when i push another button, not constantly making a new socket.

This is the code which I use:

```
public class DroidCommV1Activity extends Activity {
    Socket nsocket; //Network Socket
    public Handler mHandler;
    ImageView ivResponse;
    Button get, stop;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHandler = new Handler();

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    get = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
    ivResponse = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivResponse);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
    get.setOnClickListener(getlistener);
    stop.setOnClickListener(stopListener);

}

private OnClickListener getlistener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.67", 8080);
        nsocket = new Socket();
    try {
         nsocket.connect(sockaddr, 5000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //10 second connection timeout
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);

}
};

 private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
          new NetworkTask().execute();
       mHandler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 2000);
   }
};
  private OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
         mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
          try {
            nsocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
};

  public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Integer> {

      InputStream nis; //Network Input Stream
      OutputStream nos; //Network Output Stream
    Bitmap mp;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer test) {
                ivResponse.setImageBitmap(mp);     
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

                nis = nsocket.getInputStream();
                nos = nsocket.getOutputStream();
                nos.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                nos.flush();
                mp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(nis);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: IOException");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Exception");

        } finally {
             try {
                nis.close();
                  nos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Finished");
        }
        return 1;
    }    
  }
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
 threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at      com.droidcomm.v1.DroidCommV1Activity$NetworkTask.doInBackground(DroidCommV1Activity.java:230)
  at com.droidcomm.v1.DroidCommV1Activity$NetworkTask.doInBackground(DroidCommV1Activity.java:1)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
  ... 4 more
```